# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token new

Tags: javascript

i am playing with backbone and i have an error when i am using the model as array, can any one tell me where i am wrong?

```
$(function () {
  var Rectangle = Backbone.Model.extend({});
  var RectangleView = Backbone.View.extend({
    .....
  });

  var models [ 
    new Rectangle({
        width: 100,
        height: 60,
        position: {
            x: 300,
            y: 150
        },
        color: '#ff0000'
    })
  ];

  _(models).each(function(rmodel) {
     $('div#canvas').append(new RectangleView({ model: rmodel}).render().el);
  });
})();
```

it is coming from the array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed a `=`

```
var models = [ 
    new Rectangle({
        width: 100,
        height: 60,
        position: {
            x: 300,
            y: 150
        },
        color: '#ff0000'
    })

];
```